# Windows XP Wifi connected but can not access Internet with browser

Tags: windows-xp, wireless-networking, router, firewall, internet-connection

I have two laptops:

1. **Windows Vista** laptop which connects fine to Internet *(writing this post from it now)*
2. **Windows XP SP2** laptop which connects fine to Wifi, Router but not Internet

When I try to connect to the Internet via Firefox or IE on the XP laptop the browsers fail to connect. When I open the Wireless Network Connection Status window it says:

***Connection***

- *Status:* Connected
- *Network:* MyNetwork
- *Duration:* 53:20
- *Speed:* 54.0 Mbps
- *Signal Strength:* (an image of 5 bars and all are green)

***Activity***

- *Packets Sent:* 96,443
- *Packets Received:* 89,505

*It basically looks like this image below, with the little lock icon except the two screens are blue and sometimes gray in my version:*

[image]

In my ***Network Connections > LAN or High-Speed Internet*** window I see:

- **Local Area Connection** has a red X next to it because I am not plugged in with Ethernet cable.
- The **Wireless Network Connection** says it is Connected, Firewalled Intel(R) Pro/Wireless 3945ABG Network Connection
- Then I see another connection *(not sure what this one is for)* called **1394 Connection** Connected, Firewalled 1394 Net Adapter

When I open up Command Prompt and enter `ipconfig` I get three main sections under **Windows IP Configuration**:

- **Ethernet adapter {2EDECBB3-DC69-40BB-ADCC-398D8A1734B2}:**
  Media State ................ : Media disconnected
- **Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:**
  Media State ................ : Media disconnected
- **Ethernet adapter Wireless Network Connection:**
  Connection-specific DNS Suffix . :
  IP Address ................ : 192.168.1.101
  Subnet Mask ............... : 255.255.255.0
  Default Gateway ........... : 192.168.1.1

Now I try pinging because I realize this is one way to find out if there is a problem. My ping tests follow:

`ping google.com` = success `Packets: Sent = 4, Recieved = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss)`

`ping 127.0.0.1` = success `Packets: Sent = 4, Recieved = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss)`

`ping 192.168.1.101` = failure `Packets: Sent = 4, Recieved = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss)`

`ping 192.168.1.1` = success `Packets: Sent = 4, Recieved = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss)`

Now on to **Windows Firewall**. When I try turning it off and going to a webpage on Firefox or IE I still can not connect to the Internet/webpage. Also, Firefox is checked in the list of exceptions in the **Windows Firewall** window.

I should mention that the other day an iTunes/Apple Software Update window popped up randomly. I assume that somehow it was connecting to the Internet and got a message from Apple to update the software. Also, in my Notification Bar I see the yellow shield icon. Clicking it brings up the Windows XP **Automatic Updates** window and it says I have 5 updates ready to install. When I click install on both the Apple and Windows update windows I get failure to install messages. So perhaps it is connecting via one port but when it attempts to download it is being blocked by the firewall? Not sure.

**What should my next step be in getting connected to the Internet?**

Comment: In the IE preferences, make sure that you aren't set to use a non-existent proxy server. It's possible that this somehow got set without your knowledge.

Comment: That is my first thought as well.  A proxy [possibly set by a virus]

Comment: @Joe But how does that explain Firefox not working?

Comment: same problem on windows7
click on the wireless connection icon in left lower corner. or open the network connections icon. click properties on the wireless connection... under internet protocol (tcp/ip) highlight it and click properties. make sure it says obtain ip address automatically. write down the numbers you see before you do that just incase it doesnt work. then see if a website like google comes up.. credits:
http://ccm.net/forum/affich-487006-wireless-connected-but-no-internet-access

Answer (score 3):

That "ping 192.168.1.101 = failure" is a major clue. I suspect that either your TCP/IP is goofed up, or your C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\HOSTS file has been changed.

First, I would try a simple `ipconfig/release` then `ipconfig/renew` and try that `ping 192.168.1.101` again.

Second, try updating your wireless driver. That may fix unseen problems.

I would then reset my TCP/IP with this command: `netsh int ip reset` then reboot.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/299357

As in the comments, I would not rule out a virus either. Scan with Malwarebytes, Superantispyware, and Hitman Pro.